# Running a simple c web server in background

Tags: c, server

I have a simple code which act as a web server (just accepts the request from URL). Below is the code taken from [here](http://blog.manula.org/2011/05/writing-simple-web-server-in-c.html)

```
#include<netinet/in.h>    
#include<stdio.h>    
#include<stdlib.h>    
#include<sys/socket.h>    
#include<sys/stat.h>    
#include<sys/types.h>    
#include<unistd.h>    
    
int main() {    
   int create_socket, new_socket;    
   socklen_t addrlen;    
   int bufsize = 1024;    
   char *buffer = malloc(bufsize);    
   struct sockaddr_in address;    
 
   if ((create_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) > 0){    
      printf("The socket was created\n");
   }
    
   address.sin_family = AF_INET;    
   address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;    
   address.sin_port = htons(15000);    
    
   if (bind(create_socket, (struct sockaddr *) &address, sizeof(address)) == 0){    
      printf("Binding Socket\n");
   }
    
    
   while (1) {    
      if (listen(create_socket, 10) < 0) {    
         perror("server: listen");    
         exit(1);    
      }    
    
      if ((new_socket = accept(create_socket, (struct sockaddr *) &address, &addrlen)) < 0) {    
         perror("server: accept");    
         exit(1);    
      }    
    
      if (new_socket > 0){    
         printf("The Client is connected...\n");
      }
        
      recv(new_socket, buffer, bufsize, 0);    
      printf("%s\n", buffer);    
    write(new_socket, "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n", 16);
    write(new_socket, "Content-length: 46\n", 19);
    write(new_socket, "Content-Type: text/html\n\n", 25);
    write(new_socket, "<html><body><H1>Hello A</H1></body></html>",46);   
      close(new_socket);    
   }    
   close(create_socket);    
   return 0;    
}
```

When I run it, I do not get the terminal control back.

How can I run it in the background so that I have my terminal back?

I followed some suggestions as:

- $ ./sample &
- $ ./sample & > /dev/null
- $ nohup ./sample &

but all these has the same effect as **$ ./sample**

Some suggestions were about using fork but I have no idea how to implement that.

Appreciate some help.

Comment: On which operating system

Answer (score 2):

<sup>I guess that you are on Linux</sup>

> I followed some suggestions as:
>
> ```
>  $ ./sample &
>  $ ./sample & > /dev/null
>  $ nohup ./sample &
> ```
>
> but all these has the same effect as $ ./sample

Are you sure of that? You should have gotten a shell prompt on the terminal (which you won't have got with only  `./sample`  command). Of course you should not type the `$`, it is a [shell prompt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface#Command_prompt).

Regarding [fork](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_%28system_call%29), we don't have time to explain it in an answer (it is tricky to understand). Take several hours or days to read several chapters of [Advanced Linux Programming](http://www.makelinux.net/alp/) or some other Unix or POSIX programming book, and read [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html)

You might consider using [daemon(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/daemon.3.html) (which internally would call [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html)...) and maybe [syslog(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/syslog.3.html) (in particular if you pass `noclose` as `0` or `false` to `daemon`)

Perhaps you might start your `main` with

```
int main(int argc, char**argv) {    
 int create_socket= -1, new_socket= -1;    
 socklen_t addrlen =0;    
 int bufsize = 1024;    
 char *buffer = malloc(bufsize);
 if (!buffer) { perror("malloc buffer"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
 if (argc > 1 && !strcmp(argv[1], "-d")) {
    printf("daemonizing...\n"); fflush(NULL);
    if (daemon(/*nochdir*/true, /*noclose*/true)) 
      { perror("daemon failed"; exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
    printf("daemonized, pid %d\n", (int)getpid());
 }
```

So that when you run `./sample -d` it will daemonize itself, that is run the server as a daemon (forked) process.

BTW, **the** full **[HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) protocol is quite *complex*** (specified in more than a hundred pages). You might **consider using some HTTP server library like [libonion](https://www.coralbits.com/libonion/)**.

Don't forget to compile with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`) and to use the debugger (`gdb`) and perhaps also `strace` and `valgrind` ...

PS. In fact you'll need [ten years](http://norvig.com/21-days.html) to learn programming. Copying some random C code downloaded somewhere and editing it blindly is IMHO worthless (and potentially could harm your system). You should understand well what the program is doing.

Comment: To be exact, I am running this on Ubuntu and none of the commands return the shell prompt. I have basic knowledge of fork, it's just I don't understand how to build this using fork. I request you to give some sample or modified code if possible. Actually, this is just a use case for something I am working on, I am  not working on C programming and it would take lot of time to understand and write a program.

Comment: i cannot help more in a few minutes. Follow the references I gave you. Perhaps use `strace`  to understand what is happening. If you don't have hours to spend on learning more, give up.

Comment: If you don't know about C programming, give up your entire goal, or spend weeks learning about C programming.

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion, I suggest you to give up your arrogance.

Comment: But again, there is no point blindly copying some C code and trying to improve it without knowledge of C and POSIX programming.

Comment: I agree with your point, and as must you have seen that I took the initial code from somewhere too. My job is not to develop code, the concerned person is not available and my work is stuck because of this so I thought of looking into it.

Comment: Then use an existing HTTP framework (like `libonion`, or whatever you want) to do the job...